# Java String replaceAll regex to remove everything except digits, dots and spaces

Tags: java, regex, string

I've browsed a lot of regex topics but none of these lead me to success in my particular situation.

(Using java) I have some charsequence which I then convert to array and extract numbers to array of doubles.

> asdsad 59 asdf .2 asdf 56 89 .a 2.4 wef 95 asdf.

then I want to use regex to remove the extra part and compose the following string

> 59 2 56 89 2.4 95

so then I could just use `.split(" ")` and put them all to an array of doubles.

Until this moment I used the following expression

```
[^0-9.\s]
```

but it leaves the extra dots and therefore not reliable. Now I'm trying something like

```
[^0-9.\s]|([^0-9]\.[^0-9])
```

but it's not working at all, I'm not really good with regex, so could you explain me why the last expression is not working and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split directly on this regex:

```
([^\d.]|\B\.|\.\B)+
```

ie

```
String[] parts = str.split("([^\\d.]|\\B\\.|\\.\\B)+");
```

Although this (may) leave a leading blank in the array.

To go directly to a `double[]` in one line (handling the leading blank):

```
double[] numbers = Arrays.stream(str.split("([^\\d.]|\\B\\.|\\.\\B)+"))
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
    .toArray();
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/kUJCcy).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `string.replaceAll("[^\\d\\. ]","")`?

You can see the results here: https://regex101.com/r/X6gLaY/2

```
String string = "asdsad 59 asdf 2 asdf 56 89 .a 2.4 wef 95 asdf.";
String regex = "[^\\d\\. ]| \\.|\\.$";
System.out.println(string.replaceAll(regex,""));
```

Java example: http://ideone.com/w4BWOZ

Outputs:
`59  2  56 89 2.4  95`

Comment: yep, string.split(" ") would yield [59  2  56 89 . 2.4  95 .] in this case, which is not what I want, cause I want to parse each part as a double

Comment: Hm, actually it's not a half-hearted and not very good solution because periods between letters still stand out on themselves. I've voted to delete this post as I actually don't have the time to flesh this out better, and would have for this to be seen as a well though out attempt.

Answer (score 2):

I've played with regex for half a day until I come up with this.

Apparently it really matters what the order of the expression is. I assume it's because it iterates over each condition and always uses the data that's left after execution of previous condition, so I changed the regular expression to:

1. exclude all **dots** followed by **non-digit**
2. exclude all **non-digits** followed by **dot**
3. exclude all **left-over non-digits**

```
[^0-9]\.|\.[^0-9]|[^0-9.\s]
```

Now it works like a charm. Hope it helps someone. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add an alternative to remove dots that are not preceded with a digit that is followed with a dot and a digit:

```
[^\d\s.]+|(?<!\d\.\d)\.
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bGkhEg/3).

**Details**:

- `[^\d\s.]+` - 1+ chars other than digits, whitespaces and dots
- `|` - or
- `(?<!\d\.\d)` - a location not preceded with a digit, dot, digit
- `\.` - a dot.

Sample code:

```
String re = "[^\\d\\s.]+|(?<!\\d\\.\\d)\\.";
System.out.println("asdsad 59 asdf 2 asdf 56 89 .a 2.4 wef 95 asdf.".replaceAll(re, ""));
System.out.println("asdsad 59 asdf .2 asdf 56 89 .a 2.4 wef 95 asdf.".replaceAll(re, ""));
```

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/4Q5On5)

Comment: sorry my bad, the example did not include all possibilities, please see the new string example, when I use the alternative for dots followed by a digit, it doesn't remove the dot before a digit, so I still trying to make it remove the digit in case if it's not surrounded by digits on both sides

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but still it's not working because it parses "2.4" as "2 4". I've succeeded with a regex and answered my own question, it's almost perfect, except that it will crash on strings like "4.4.4", but that's okay so far. Still Your elaboration gave me the right direction so thank you again :)